# Setting up Nginx Proxy in Docker using Ansible

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker, ansible

I am attempting to setup an nginx container that serves as a proxy to another container I have setup. I would like to automate this setup as I need to deploy a similar setup across several servers. For this I am using Ansible.

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.14:9000;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my Ansible YAML file:

```
- name: Install Nginx
      docker:
        name: nginx
        image: nginx
        detach: True
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        volumes:
            - /etc/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

When I first run my playbook, nginx is running but is not bound to `8080` as seen here:

```
6a4f610e86d nginx "nginx -g 'daemon off" 35 minutes ago   Up Less than a second  80/tcp, 443/tcp nginx
```

However, if I run the nginx container directly with:

```
docker run -d -v /etc/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -p 8080:8080 nginx
```

nginx and my proxy runs as expected and is listening on `8080`:

```
c3a46421045c nginx "nginx -g 'daemon off" 2 seconds ago Up 1 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp determined_swanson
```

Any idea why it works one way but not the other?

**Update**

Per the guidance given in the selected answer, I updated my YAML file thusly:

```
- name: Install Nginx
  docker:
    name: nginx
    image: nginx
    detach: True
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    expose:
        - 8080
    volumes:
        - /etc/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure your nginx image `EXPOSE` the port 8080, and you can specify directly in your ansible yaml file:

```
expose
(added in 1.5)
```

> List of additional container ports to expose for port mappings or links. If the port is already exposed using EXPOSE in a Dockerfile, you don't need to expose it again.

Then, the only other difference I see when considering the [Ansible docker module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) is that the port are inside double-quotes:

```
ports:
    - "8080:9000"
```

Also, if you want to prexypass to another container in the same docker daemon, you might want to use a link instead of a fixed IP address.

```
links:
    - "myredis:aliasedredis"
```

That way, your nginx.conf includes a fixed rule:

```
proxy_pass http://aliasedredis:9000;
```

Comment: Thanks - I went ahead and tried the quotes just to make sure, but it still doesn't bind to port 8080. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Louis you need to be sure your nginx image does EXPOSE the port 8080

Comment: Yup `expose` was exactly what I needed. If you want to update your answer, I'll accept it.